# Testear el valor de retorno de una función sin llamarla directamente

Tags: python, test, mock

Tengo una función `foo` a la que llamo dentro de `faa`.
Quiero hacer un test para comprobar que `foo`, al ser llamada dentro de `faa`, devuelve el valor esperado.
Sé que lo habitual para testear `foo` sería llamar a `foo` en mi test, pero quiero comprobar que `faa` hace la llamada de forma correcta.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

De momento lo he conseguido con esta solución torpe:

```
import inspect
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Callable
from unittest import mock

@contextmanager
def mock_sin_reemplazo(para_mock: Callable):
    # Path completo a la función
    funcion_path = para_mock.__qualname__
    definicion_path = Path(inspect.getfile(para_mock)).with_suffix('')
    src_path = next(parent for parent in definition_path.parents
                    if parent.name == 'src')
    definicion_relativa = definicion_path.relative_to(src_path.parent)
    funcion_path = '.'.join((*relative_definition.parts, funcion_path))

    # Guardo el valor de retorno de cada llamada
    valores_de_retorno = []
    def side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
        valor_de_retorno = para_mock(*args, **kwargs)
        valores_de_retorno.append(valor_de_retorno)
        return valor_de_retorno

    # Devuelvo el mock con el contenedor de valores de retorno
    with mock.patch(funcion_path, side_effect=side_effect) as funcion_mock:
        setattr(funcion_mock, 'valores_de_retorno', valores_de_retorno)
        yield funcion_mock
```

Lo cual me permite escribir un test bastante limpio:

```
from src.a import foo, faa

def test_foo():
    with mock_sin_reemplazo(foo) as mock_foo:
        faa()
        assert mock_foo.valores_de_retorno[0] == "Valor Esperado"
```

También he intentado `mock.patch.object(para_mock, '__call__', side_effect=para_mock)`.
Lo cual no funciona porque las llamadas a función no usan `__call__`.

¿Hay alguna forma canónica de conseguir mi objetivo?

Comment: ¿Qué estás probando? `faa`? Entonces necesitas mockear lo que devuelve `foo`. Pero luego dices: *Quiero hacer un test para comprobar que `foo` devuelve el valor esperado*, entonces ese test debes hacerlo sobre `foo` y no sobre `faa`. Pero por lo visto quieres probarlo desde `faa`. El test entonces ya NO es UNITARIO. Por favor explica un poco mejor lo que intentas hacer, tal vez me estoy enredando con tu explicación. Saludos

Comment: Yo nunca he dicho que sea un test unitario. Quiero comprobar que `foo` al ser llamado desde `faa` devuelva el valor esperado.

Comment: ¿Que tal si como argumento de faa le pasas una variable test  que al ser true retorna el valor de foo?

Comment: Lo mas recomendable con los test es simular el argumento que se le va a pasar y llamar a la funcion con ese argumento

Comment: @DanielBriceño Soy consciente de que lo recomendable y canónico para testear `foo` es llamar a `foo` y comprobar su valor de retorno. Pero si preparo la llamada a `foo` en el test, estoy en un entorno demasiado controlado como para que me asegure que al llamar a `faa`, `foo` se vaya a ejecutar correctamente.

Comment: Realmente la unica recomendacion que te puedo dar es esta: ¿Que tal si como argumento de faa le pasas una variable test que al ser true retorna el valor de foo?. Pues ni si quiera se como se ve ni foo ni faa